# How can I select unique rows from a table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns artist, title, album and other columns for dates, ip etc
now i want to display unique artist title and album in a row
like say,

```
artist , album, title
a , b , c
a , b , c
d , e , f
a , b , d
```

then it must display

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
a,b,d
```

how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `DISTINCT` keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT artist, title, album 
FROM YourTable
```

But it doesn't seem as though your design is normalised if these are being repeated in each row.

(Edit after comments.) It seems you need other columns but you don't care which of the possible matching values are shown in these. In that case you can use `GROUP BY` As far as I understand in MySQL if you don't specify selected columns in the `GROUP BY` you would get this but it's completely invalid in all other RDBMSs.

```
SELECT artist,
       title,
       album,
       id,
       link,
       artistlink,
       albumlink,
       songlength,
       ip,
       timestamp,
       image
FROM   wp_air1nowplaying_unique
GROUP  BY artist,
          title,
          album
ORDER  BY artist ASC,
          album ASC,
          title ASC
```

In other RDBMSs you would need to wrap these in an aggregate. e.g.

```
SELECT artist,
       title,
       album,
       MAX(id)         id,
       MAX(link)       link,
       MAX(artistlink) artistlink,
       MAX(albumlink)  albumlink,
       MAX(songlength) songlength,
       MAX(ip)         ip,
```

The values returned could very well be from different rows with the above. To avoid this you would use a [`greatest-n-per-group`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+greatest-n-per-group) query

Comment: this this the right way? SELECT DISTINCT (artist title, album) , id, link, artistlink, albumlink, songlength, ip, timestamp, image FROM wp_air1nowplaying_unique ORDER BY artist ASC, album ASC, title ASC

Comment: Can a particular artist title, album have multiple different albumlinks (for example)?

Comment: So if you only have 1 row for each `artist title, album` which value should the `albumlinks` column contain (and `ip` etc.)?

Comment: they can have any doesn't matter ORDER BY artist ASC, album ASC, title ASC the first one

Comment: And is it important that they all come from the same row or not?

Comment: the only thing important is artist, title, album others can be anythign but there must be some data for them

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `artist`, `album`, `cover` FROM `yourtable`;
```